# How can I make a custom session provider work with ASP.NET 5? Specically use Redis for sessions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redis, asp.net-core, stackexchange.redis

In ASP.NET MVC 4, to switch out the default session provider for a custom one, you had to let the app know via web.config, which now is gone in ASP.NET 5.

I've tried to use Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider (which is based on StackExchange.Redis), but not sure how to proceed beyond getting it via NuGet.  It simply doesn't work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Following is a Session sample where you can use Redis cache as a store for it:

https://github.com/aspnet/Session/blob/dev/samples/SessionSample/Startup.cs#L32-L39

You can configure Redis cache options like below:

```
services.Configure<RedisCacheOptions>(redisOptions =>
{
    redisOptions.Configuration = "localhost";
    redisOptions.InstanceName = "SampleInstance";
}
```

Comment: The example doesn't say how to set the IP and password of the Redis server.

Comment: @KiranChalla It didn't help me...  For some reason, that doesn't make sense to me, it thinks that Configuration property is of type IConfiguration, where as in real life, its a string.

Comment: @AngryHacker: Looks like my sample was incorrect...updated it now.

Comment: @KiranChalla It compiles...however, I still can't make the actual session work.  Would you happen to have a sample project where you save the session to a Redis box?

Answer (score 3):

At one point a couple months ago I had an app (similar to https://github.com/aspnet/Session/blob/dev/samples/SessionSample/Startup.cs) connecting to a remote Redis server like this:

```
app.UseDistributedSession(new RedisCache(new RedisCacheOptions() 
{ 
     Configuration = "ip:port,password=xxx"
}));
```

It's probably different now in beta7, but hopefully that helps.

Comment: Would you mind posting that app somewhere (or a skeleton of it).  No matter what I've tried (including the code above), it just simply doesn't work with the latest beta.

Comment: Here you go https://gist.github.com/opiethehokie/338630cbf12a8a80e851. I was trying to run it in Cloud Foundry so my Redis credentials were coming from an environment variable, you can ignore that part. It didn't work on Linux though, it only worked on Windows.

Comment: Yeah, I am running it on windows as well.  Your code helped and I am further along now.  The piece that I was missing is that everything must be setup *before* you call app.UseMvc.  I was setting up the session after the fact.  

Anyway, at this point I call `Context.Session.SetString("foo", "bar");` in my Controller action and get `ERR unknown command 'EVAL'`.  Any idea where to go from here?